# Python/Pandas - Breaking postal code into postal and extension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following column in pandas dataframe which has postal code -

```
postal code
56789-2345
45675
null
23445-445
1234-45
34567
```

I need to break it into postal code and ext like below -

```
Postal code     postal_ext
56789           2345
45675
null
23445           445
1234            45
34567
```

How can i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `split`

```
out = df['postal code'].str.split('-',expand=True)
out.columns = ['Postal code','postal_ext']

out
  Postal code postal_ext
0       56789       2345
1       45675       None
2         NaN        NaN
3       23445        445
4        1234         45
5       34567       None
```

Comment: How to do this when dataframe has other columns too?